# Android WebView doesn't support this URL ... how can i get the exact view like webpage

Tags: android, browser, webview

I have a problem with android `WebView`.

The following URL loads correctly in system browser, but not in Android emulator browser, Samsung galaxy mobile or lg mobiles.

I need to show the page the same as system browser view in my app.

Please help me to come out of this problem.

Url : [This is the link](http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/wwacapget.php?x=MA124CA0B5C008.RedFlagWarning.124CA0B6FD9CMA.BOXRFWBOX.835121ef7181220c68e2838a75b2cb97)

Comment: they may be doing useragent detection to decide what to display

Answer (score 0):

I can open the URL in Opera for Android.
Have you tried it?

Comment: Not Yet @Mohan Sinfh i wil try and let u know .